# Unable to read a state from a reactjs component after it is set

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have set a simple example here: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KhBJPs2jLmpQcCTSRBk

This is my class in the question:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class RedirectMessage extends Component {

  componentWillMount () {
    const { timeToRedirect } = this.props;
    const time = timeToRedirect || 5000;
    console.log(`timer is set to ${time}`)
    this.timer = setInterval(this.setoffRedirect.bind(this), time)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  setoffRedirect () {
    console.log('setoffRedirect');
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    this.setState({startRedirect: true})
  }

  getDestination() {
    const { destination }  = this.props;
    return destination || '/';
  }

  render() {
    const {
      message,
      startRedirect
    } = this.props;

    console.log(`setoffRedirect >>> ${startRedirect}`);
    if (startRedirect) {
      return (
        <Redirect to={this.getDestination()} />
      )
    }
    return (
      <div >
        {message}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default RedirectMessage;
```

What I want to achieve is to display a message before I redirect to another url

Here are the logic:

1. set up a timer in `componentWillMount`
2. When the timer callback is called, it uses `setState` to set `startRedirect` to true
3. In `render` if `startRedirect` is true, a `Redirect` tag will be rendered can cause url redirect

However the problem is the `startRedirect` remains undefined even after the timer callback is called. What have I missed?

Comment: state will in your case be undefined, if you create a constructor for your class, and set this.state = {}, then you can access the state object.

Comment: You are setting state variable `startRedirect` and inside render method you are trying to read `startRedirect` from props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SomeClass extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {startRedirect: false};
    }
}
```

The state object is not defined when using classes (es6). In cases where it is needed, you need to define it in the constructor to make it accessible.

You are also targeting startRedirect from this.props, instead of this.state within render

Comment: So you mean something like `if (this.state.startRedirect) {`?

Comment: in your sample, you are targeting this.props.startRedirect, instead of this.state.startRedirect.